Boundedness of countable union of bounded sets
Let $(B_n)_n$ be a sequence of bounded sets in a locally convex topological vector space.
In the context of Fréchet spaces, one can always find a sequence of scalars $c_n$ such that $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} c_n B_n$ is still bounded.
(Using the metric.)

Is there a name for spaces having this property, i.e.:
$$
\forall \text{ sequences of bounded sets } (B_n)_n \, \exists (c_n)_n \colon \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} c_n B_n \text{ is bounded}
.
$$
Does this property naturally pop-up somewhere?


You set this in an arbitrary TVS. What is your definition of boundedness for TVS that do not have a metric?

Good catch! I meant locally convex TVS.

This is called Mackey's first countability property. See the original paper.
